# Assert specific constructor called by child class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reflection, constructor

I am trying to write a test to verify that child classes call a specific base class' constructor. Effectively, IDs for my entities are generated when the object is instantiated by the server. I am using NHibernate as my ORM, and so I need a 0-parameter constructor. I would prefer that this constructor not generate a Guid everytime that NHibernate hydrates an entity, so I created a second constructor for my base entity with a Guid as a paramter.

It looks something like this

```
public abstract class EntityBase {
    public Guid ID {get; protected set;}

    protected EntityBase() { }

    public EntityBase(Guid id) { ID = id }

    public static Guid NewID => GenerateGuid();
}

public class Entity : EntityBase {
    public int X {get; set;}

    protected Entity() { }

    public Entity(int x) : base(NewID) { X = x; }
}
```

This test I want to write should assert that all constructors (except the 0-parameter constructor) of all concrete child classes of EntityBase call the correct base constructor:

> public EntityBase(Guid id) { ID = id }

Currently, my code loops through constructors on all concrete classes assignable from EntityBase, but I don't know how to make the final check. Research into solutions suggested attempting to read IL using reflection. I considered trying to check if 'NewID' had been called, but was unable to find any accomplish that either.

Is there a way to achieve this, or is my solution to the NHibernate problem the real issue?

Comment: Can ID be changed by the derived class after being instantiated? If not, why not just change it to a private set and then check that it has been set? Or is your problem more complicated than that? Hmm, I guess it is unit test and somebody could easily change "protected" to "public"...

Comment: No, it cannot be changed after instantiation. I want to write a unit test to enforce the correct constructor behavior. If I try to invoke every constructor and check if the ID field is set, then I need to find some way to instantiate an unknown set of parameters for every possible present and future constructor. Additionally, if the constructors for the child classes use properties of their parameters, then I would need to make sure that those fields are populated also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so this took me a while but I like a challenge.

A caveat before we start: some of the OperandType values are not listed on MSDN in terms of byte size, so I can't be sure that this is parsing everything properly.

You pass in the derived and base constructors, and then it works out if that constructor has been called or not.

```
public bool IsCalled(ConstructorInfo derivedConstructor, ConstructorInfo baseConstructor)
{
    var body = derivedConstructor.GetMethodBody();
    var expectedConstructorToken = baseConstructor.MetadataToken;
    byte[] il = body.GetILAsByteArray();

    var codes = new Dictionary<short, OpCode>();
    var fields = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        var value = field.GetValue(null);
        if (!(value is OpCode)) { continue; }
        var opCode = (OpCode)value;
        codes.Add(opCode.Value, opCode);
    }

    var operandSizes = new Dictionary<OperandType, int>();
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.operandtype(v=vs.110).aspx
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineBrTarget, 4);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineField, 4);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineI, 4);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineI8, 8);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineMethod, 4);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineNone, 0);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineR, 8);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineSig, 4);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineString, 4);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineSwitch, 4);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineType, 32);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.InlineVar, 2);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget, 1);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.ShortInlineI, 1);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.ShortInlineR, 4);
    operandSizes.Add(OperandType.ShortInlineVar, 1);

    var i = 0;
    while(i < il.Length) {
        OpCode operation = OpCodes.Nop;
        if (il[i] == 0xfe)
        {
            operation = codes[BitConverter.ToInt16(il, i)];
        }
        else
        {
            operation = codes[(short)il[i]];
        }
        i += operation.Size;

        if (operation.OperandType == OperandType.InlineMethod)
        {
            var token = BitConverter.ToInt32(il, i);
            if (token == expectedConstructorToken) { return true; }
        }

        i += operandSizes[operation.OperandType];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
var derivedConstructor = typeof(Derived).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int) });
var baseConstructor = typeof(Base).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int) });
bool isCalled = IsCalled(derivedConstructor, baseConstructor);
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts john - this will definitely get me started. I am marking this as the correct answer. For anyone else viewing this, this snippet will NOT work for nested base constructors. To be clear, if we introduce a 3rd entity, Entity2 : Entity, and call use this on Entity2's constructor, it will not detect EntityBase's constructor. You will need to recursively traverse the class hierarchy.

Comment: This also does not work for references to other constructors in the same class using "this" before moving to the base constructor

Comment: I added an edit to correct for your double-counting of the opcode size.

Comment: @Derek Oh, oops! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to [detect which base constructor is called by each constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3402580/1178314), check if no-args constructor is only called by no-args non public constructor, and do that recursively on the class hierarchy till your base class.

Comment: Huh, I was just working on an answer that does what Mark Cidade suggested for #1 :)